# How to select element for Chrome SnappySnippet?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I must have tried a hundred time by now to select an html element and then create a snippet with Chrome [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil?hl=en), but each time I get the error

```
Error! DOM snapshot could not be created. Make sure that you have inspected some element.
```

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if5pXoIJ4EU) it looks easy, but out of those 100 times, I have been able to make it work once with something random.

**Question**

Is the selection somehow time based, so I have to click on SnappySnippet in e.h. less than a second?

How do you keep the selected element, so when moving the mouse to the SnappySnippet button other elements are not selected from hovering them?

Comment: Removing [tag:google-chrome-extension], since it does not concern extension development. It is, however, on-topic on Stack Overflow in my opinion, since it's a primarily developer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tree-DOM menu, left click on a `div` so it becomes dark blue. Now it is selected even thought hovering the mouse over other `div`'s it will remain selected.

The problem you have is probably because SnappySnippet can't handle large `div`'s. Try with a very small one first.